# Aplicativo Android e Banco de Dados MySQL

Tags: android, sql, banco-de-dados, mysql

Tenho um aplicativo desenvolvido em Android e preciso me conectar a um banco de dados MySQL que está local em um Desktop. Consigo facilmente o endereço de IP da máquina onde está o banco. Como posso efetuar a conexão entre o aplicativo e o banco MySQL local no Desktop sem a utilização de webservices?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa solução do StackOverflow em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946065/android-how-to-connect-an-android-phone-to-computers-localhost

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer isso usando JODBC mysql e AsyncTask, fazendo conexão direta. Não esqueça de colocar o jodbc na pasta libs do seu projeto.